# What does saying a phylogenetic tree is 'well resolved' mean?

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogenetics

I'm not sure what 'resolution' means in the context of phylogenies.

Answer (score 1):

It means incomplete separation or a failure to split into two groups unambiguously.

There are multiple ways to estimate the resolution of a phylogenetic tree; involving an index to measure the likelihood of observing the phylogenetic tree that you derive relative to those produced by drawing species at random, for instance, or permuting species to produce a null distribution.

A badly resolved tree should show up in sets of randomly generated trees far more often than well resolved ones.

See http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2012.00196.x/abstract

Comment: I think PO asks what **well** - resolved means

Comment: My bad, well spotted, Alice.